# Proof: $xy=0\Rightarrow x=0$ or $y=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

x,y are in the field $K$.

Show that $xy=0\Rightarrow x=0\vee y=0$.

Proof by contradiction, lets assume the negation of the claim.

$(x\cdot y=0)\wedge(x\not=0)\wedge(y\not=0)$

$x\cdot y=0$

$x^{-1}xy=0$ which is perfectly fine, as $x\not=0$.

$y=0$

$y^{-1} y=0$ see above

$1=0$ which is a contradiction of the field-axiom that $1\not=0$.

Is this a valid proof or do i need to elobrate more in the steps?

Comment: Well, funny enough, the contradiction appears before $1 = 0$: it appears at $y=0$ ;)

Comment: The line $y=0$ is already a contradiction... Why continue past that? In fact, going on to write $y^{-1}$ after the line $y=0$ is simply invalid.

Comment: @rschwieb oh, i did not recognize that!

Comment: As an exercise of logic: $xy=0\Rightarrow x=0$ or $y=0$ is equivalent to $xy=0$ and $x\ne0 \Rightarrow  y=0$

Comment: @Momo $(xy=0)\wedge (x\not=0)\wedge (y\not=0)$ is the negation of your second statement, it's also the negation of the first statement. (altho i skipped the brackets). Therefore both statements are the same, but formulated in another way? (i dont know if that is valid)

Comment: Your argument is right. I usually go by the definition $p\Rightarrow Q\equiv \neg p \vee q$. But after so many years, it goes automatically. In your case: $xy=0 \Rightarrow x=0 \vee y=0 \equiv \neg xy=0 \vee (x=0 \vee y=0) \equiv (\neg xy=0 \vee x=0) \vee y=0 \equiv \neg (xy=0 \wedge x\ne0) \vee y=0 \equiv xy=0 \wedge x\ne0 \Rightarrow y=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is valid. You may shorten it by simply assuming $x\ne 0$ and proving $y=0$, getting rid of the unnecessary steps.

Comment: As written, the line $y=0$ followed by $yy^{-1}=0$ is *not* a valid deduction . But the suggestion to shorten it fixes it all the same.